# ¿Como generar fechas con json?

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

Buen día, trabajando con este [calendario](http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/#Examples/Full%20example)  hay una parte en la que colorea unos días, entonces en el dataSource cambie el código:

```
dataSource: 
                [
                    {
                    url : 'calendario/dataSource.jsp',
                    }
                ]
```

En el JSP me genera lo siguiente: `{"endDate":"new Date(2010, 07, 20)","startDate":"new Date(2010, 07, 20)"}`

```
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
   consultas = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (24), fecha, 103) "
                +"FROM kalendario_entradaz "
                + "WHERE activo = 0";
    rs = MBD.SQLBD(consultas);
    while (rs.next())
    {
        x++;
    }
    MBD.desconectarBD();

    out.print("["); 

    consultas = "SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR (24), fecha, 103) "
                +"FROM kalendario_entradaz "
                + "WHERE activo = 0";
    y = 1;

    rs = MBD.SQLBD(consultas);
    while (rs.next())
    {

            fecha = rs.getString(1);
            dia=fecha.substring(0, 2);
            mes=fecha.substring(3, 5);
            anio=fecha.substring(6, 10);


            obj.put("startDate", "new Date("+anio+", "+mes+", "+dia+")");
            obj.put("endDate", "new Date("+anio+", "+mes+", "+dia+")");


        y++;

        if (y < x)
        {
            out.print(obj+","); 
        }
        else
        {
            out.print(obj); 
        }

    }
        MBD.desconectarBD();
```

He leído que como tal no puedo generar el new Date() si no que tengo que parsear

Comment: en js si puedes crear objetos `Date` con `new Date(año,mes,dia)` solo que los meses van desde 0 a 11.

Comment: Efectivamente, pero no quiero generar un new Date() por cada fecha que tengo son como 450 por eso genere esto pero tengo mis dudas